# Java ee agent for ODI

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I've created a domain for my java ee agent using : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/ODING/GUID-3F74BFAB-99E9-4060-86E8-F70A8352A701.htm#ODING292

I've also created an agent in odi studio, but when i try to test it it gives me the error:

oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.InvocationException: ODI-1425: Agent application cannot be reached using http.

```
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.reThrowAgentErrorAsInvocation(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:1716)

at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:401)

at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.support.InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:162)

at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:614)

at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:592)

at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.testOdiAgent(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:85)

at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.actionPerformed(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:76)

at com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpAgent$5.performAction(EditFrameSnpAgent.java:637)

at oracle.odi.ui.framework.event.OdiActionListener.actionPerformed(OdiActionListener.java:69)

at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)

at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)

at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)

at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)

at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)

at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)

at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)

at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)

at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)

at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)

at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)

at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)

at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Caused by: ODI-1425: Agent application cannot be reached using http.

```
at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:403)

... 45 more
```

Things I've done:

1. Telnet to the port 15101 and it's working fine.
2. Firewall is off
3. Made sure that my node manager and weblogic server are up and running.
4. Managed server for odi is up and running.

Have even tried to delete and recreate the deployment for the odiagent (http://www.redstk.com/odi-12c-agent-not-running-odi-1425/)

Nothing seems to be working and I'm at my wits end..any help will be highly appreciated.

I'm trying this on windows 10, with odi 12c

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is not a server Edition of Windows so it's very unlikely that any server-side component (like the JEE agent) of any enterprise tool would support it.
If you look at the [certification matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html), you can see that only the Server 2012 versions of Windows are supported.

Comment: Yes but i have configured odi on my system in the past. Had to redeploy the application and hence re configuring odi agent and that's when it won't start.